# How can I get the time of a facebook user?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, cherrypy

I'm building a web application which monitors the up times of friends on facebook in CherryPy (Python Web Framework) and I was wondering how it would be possible to get the time of a facebook user at any given time.

If I need to say that "friend A was online" at a specific time, it would need to match their timezones and hence I've been left a bit stumped.

I played around with the pytz module in python, however had no luck.

At the moment, I am retrieving the "timezone" for a user via the FQL and then adding the timezone value to a database:

```
user_details = fbconsole.fql("""SELECT uid, timezone, name FROM user WHERE uid = me()""")
```

I am wondering about a few things:

- Is it possible to get the time in which friends are online through Facebook API?
- Is it possible to alternatively figure out the time of the client at any given time, through using the timezone offset? (if so, how? I haven't been able to do this yet)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem myself through the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
#set user timezone (GMT +10)
user_timezone = timezone('Etc/GMT+10')
#convert local time to user time
user_timezone_time = user_timezone.localize(datetime.now())
#format in 12hr time (%I for 12 hour time and %p for AM PM clarification)
formatted_user_timezone = user_timezone_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p %Z%z')
print formatted_user_timezone
```

This allowed me to retrieve the `timezone` field from the "user" field for the Facebook API and then apply it with the code above, to find out the local time of a facebook user.

Thanks! I hope this helps others.